# Error in main.xml, How can I fix it?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I made a main.xml for my landscape layout only now I get this error:

> Error parsing XML: XML or test declaration not at start of entity.

at the bottom of it next to `RelativeLayout`.

What can I do to fix it?
Also i didn't use a `LinearLayout` cause then it gives an error at the top next to `?xml version= etc.`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/stonessea"
    android:icon="@drawable/iconrandomize" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Aantal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Laagste"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Hoogste"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textColorHighlight="#FFFFFF" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/Randomize" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="105dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `</RelativeLayout>` at the end.

Comment: `</RelativeLayout>` is at the end. There was problem with code formatting.